# Add ID column to a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list of 142 dataframes `file_content` and a list from `id_list <- list(as.character(1:length(file_content)))`

I am trying to add a new column `period` to each data frame in `file_content`.

All data frames are similar to `2021-03-16` below.

```
`2021-03-16` <- file_content[[1]] # take a look at 1/142 dataframes in file_content

head(`2021-03-16`)
     author_id                created_at           id                                                                                           tweet
1 3.304380e+09 2018-12-01 22:58:55+00:00 1.069003e+18                                          @Acosta I hope he didnâ€™t really say â€œmuckâ€\u009d.
2 5.291559e+08 2018-12-01 22:57:31+00:00 1.069003e+18      @Acosta I like Mattis, but why does he only speak this way when Individual-1 isn't around?
3 2.195313e+09 2018-12-01 22:56:41+00:00 1.069002e+18 @Acosta What did Mattis say about the informal conversation between Trump and Putin at the G20?
4 3.704188e+07 2018-12-01 22:56:41+00:00 1.069002e+18                                                           @Acosta Good! Tree huggers be damned!
5 1.068995e+18 2018-12-01 22:56:11+00:00 1.069002e+18                                                    @Acosta @NinerMBA_01
6 9.983321e+17 2018-12-01 22:55:13+00:00 1.069002e+18                                                                                 @Acosta Really?
```

I have tried to add the `period` column using the following code but it adds all 142 values from the `id_list` to every row in every data frame in `file_content`.

```
for (id in length(id_list)) {
  file_content <- lapply(file_content, function(x) { x$period <- paste(id_list[id], sep = "_"); x }) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `imap`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
imap(file_content, ~ .x %>% 
      mutate(period = .y))
```

---

Or with `Map` from `base R`

```
Map(cbind, file_content, period = names(file_content))
```

---

In the OP's code, the `id_list` is created as a `single` `list` element by wrapping with `list` i.e.

```
list(1:5)
```

vs

```
as.list(1:5)
```

Here, we don't need to convert to `list` as a vector is enough

```
id_list <- seq_along(file_content)
```

Also, the `for` loop is looping on a single element i.e. the last element with `length`

```
for (id in length(id_list)) {
            ^^
```

instead, it would be `1:length`.  In addition, the assignment should be on the single list element `file_content[[id]]` and not on the entire `list`

```
for(id in seq_along(id_list)) {
    file_content[[id]]$period <- id_list[id]
       
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a very thorough reply @akrun. I suspect `seq_long` in the for loop should be `seq_along`. However, even when that is corrected your suggestion does not add a new column to any of the data frames in `file_content`. Instead I get 50 warnings `1: In x$period <- paste(id_list[id], sep = "_") : Coercing LHS to a list`

Comment: @MarcoLiedecke that was a typo.  You don't need any `paste` here when the element you are looping is of length 1 `id_list[id]` is of length 1

Comment: @MarcoLiedecke also note that I created `id_list` as a vector i.e. `id_list <- seq_along(file_content)` instead of a list.  If you have a list, then you need to use `id_list[[id]]` insteda of `id_list[id]`

Comment: I have used `id_list <- seq_along(file_content)` in combination with the for loop.  However, it still does not add any column to the data frames. Now I get 50 errors like this `In x$period <- id_list[id] : Coercing LHS to a list`

Comment: @MarcoLiedecke Please check your `id_list`.  I already commented that if it is a `list` object, you need to use `[[` instead of `[`.  I constructed it as a vector, so i used `[`

Comment: @MarcoLiedecke sorry, now I corrected.  There were lots of syntax issues that I didn't notice the assignment code.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, the mistake is you need double brackets in `id_list[[id]]`.

```
for (id in length(id_list)) {
  file_content <- lapply(file_content, function(x) {
    x$period <- paste(id_list[[id]], sep = "_")
    x
  }) 
}
# $`1`
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 period
# 1  1  4  7 10      1
# 2  2  5  8 11      2
# 3  3  6  9 12      3
# 
# $`2`
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 period
# 1  1  4  7 10      1
# 2  2  5  8 11      2
# 3  3  6  9 12      3
# 
# $`3`
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 period
# 1  1  4  7 10      1
# 2  2  5  8 11      2
# 3  3  6  9 12      3
```

You could also try `Map()` and save a few lines.

```
Map(`[<-`, file_content, 'period', value=id_list)
# $`1`
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 period
# 1  1  4  7 10      1
# 2  2  5  8 11      2
# 3  3  6  9 12      3
# 
# $`2`
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 period
# 1  1  4  7 10      1
# 2  2  5  8 11      2
# 3  3  6  9 12      3
# 
# $`3`
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 period
# 1  1  4  7 10      1
# 2  2  5  8 11      2
# 3  3  6  9 12      3
```

---

*Data:*

```
file_content <- replicate(3, data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4)), simplify=F) |> setNames(1:3)
id_list <- list(as.character(1:length(file_content)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jay.sf. I tried both and they work as intended.  I understand the first solution using a for loop but I will have to read up on the `Map()` function.